# cURL Array from Amazon S3 PHP Class

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3

I'm currently using the [Amazon S3 PHP Class, getObjectInfo()](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#getObjectInfo)

The line I'm using is this:

```
  $info = $s3->getObjectInfo($bucketName, baseName($uploadFile));
    echo "S3::getObjecInfo(): Info for {$bucketName}/".baseName($uploadFile).': '.print_r($info, 1);
```

And it returns something like this:

```
  S3::getObjecInfo(): Info for media/7743247696.mp4: Array ( [time] => 1254199603 [hash] => 99a974c6fe806f63ab7994708ea8484b [type] => video/mp4 [size] => 4562654 )
```

Using PHP, how can I extract one bit at a time, more specifically, to get the [size] attribute so that I can add this to my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is just an associative array.  You can access elements using `$arrayName['keyName']`:

```
$info = $s3->getObjectInfo($bucketName, baseName($uploadFile));
$size = $info['size'];

echo "Size: $size";
```

Comment: Easier than I thought.  Never dealt with an associative array.  Thanks!